# How to map nginx to respond depending on requester?

Tags: php, nginx

I have an nginx server that should respond to several different websites that contain the php function:

```
file_get_contents();
```

When looking at the logs I can see the requester's ip:

```
191.56.110.18 - - [07/Mar/2013:00:46:53 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 151 "-" "-"
```

But I want nginx to map the requester's actual request page. So for instance when one of my domains uses `file_get_contents()` to get a response from the page `www.mydomaim.com/page20` then nginx will map it to a file that contains the string `"this is page 20"`

I thought maybe i'll make a request with a parameter in each of my domains with:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
```

So the call would be something like:

```
file_get_contents('http://www.nginxserver.com/?domainpage='. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
```

But that would return only the domain name and I think it's not optimal. I'm obviously new to nginx and looking for the best way to do this map functionality.

My aim is to serve static content based on the requesting page. Am I missing something? What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: If you are serving static content, you should take PHP and file_get_contents completely out of the equation. nginx's bread and butter is serving static content, so let nginx make the call to the static content. If it's serving the whole page, then just let nginx do a redirect to the content you want. If there is something else going on, like it's only part of the page, then I'm going to need more information. The main question I have is, why are you doing it this way? Why did you feel that file_get_contents was important to use in this case?

Comment: @MarkTomlin think of nginx deciding what "banner" to display on each page. It's only a part of the page. I can't do it asynchronously with javascript but have to use file_get_contents

Answer (score 0):

*based on the requesting page*:

that information is passed in the referrer http header, which is accessible from within nginx through the [$http_referer](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24http_HEADER) variable.

Keep in mind though that there is no guarantee that the referer-header will be set, or set correctly (spoofing or blocking the referer header is both easy, and semi-common)